# Valgrind : "Invalid write of size 1" after char[] to std::vector<char> migration

Tags: c++, hex, std, valgrind, heap-memory

I have a very simple hexlify method in c++ which is based against python's binascii implementation.

```
std::string Hexlify(const std::string& iData)
{
    // the same as python binascii.b2a_hex
    const size_t len = iData.size() << 1; // output will be twice as long
    char hex[len];

    const char* curdata = iData.data();
    char* curhex = hex;
    const char* end = curdata + iData.size();

    char c;
    // from python's implementation (2.7.1, if it matters)
    while(curdata <= end)
    {
        c = (*curdata>>4) & 0xf;
        c = (c>9) ? c+'a'-10 : c + '0';
        *(curhex++) = c;
        c = (*curdata) & 0xf;
        c = (c>9) ? c+'a'-10 : c + '0';
        *(curhex++) = c;
        curdata++;
    }
    return std::string(hex, len);
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now, the `hex` char[] gets allocated on the stack and it can be an issue when dealing with huge buffers which is why I wanted to migrate it to an `std::vector` to benefit from heap allocation.

```
std::string Hexlify(const std::string& iData)
{
    // the same as python binascii.b2a_hex
    const size_t len = iData.size() << 1; // output will be twice as long
    std::vector<char> hex(len);

    const char* curdata = iData.data();
    char* curhex = &hex[0];
    const char* end = curdata + iData.size();

    // SAME CODE AS BEFORE

    return std::string(&hex[0], len);
}
```

This `std::vector` implementation generates a Valgrind's "Invalid write of size 1" error.

Any idea why ?

If I make the `hex` vector two bytes bigger (one does not seem to be enough)

```
std::vector<char> hex(len + 2);
```

the error disappears from valgrind's report.

Comment: `while(curdata <= end)` will process one more character than required - the one right after string's end. So, you have array out-of-bounds error in both codes, but it's not detected in the first. Simple test: what if `iData` is empty?

Comment: As a side note, use `std::vector::data()` to get the pointer to the underlying array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're out by one.

If `iData` is say "xy", then `end` points to one after the "y". With your `<= end`, you attempt to encode 3 characters (giving 6 hex digits) into a space only big enough for 4.

Comment: How come the out of bound is not detected with the first implementation ?

Comment: because possibly the compiler isn't giving valgrind enough information about the vector size (maybe it also rounded it up a bit), whereas (again possibly) valgrind is able to dermine the exact intended vector size. I don't think valgrind claims to find every single memory access error under all circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an off-by-one error with `end`.  You can avoid that kind of tricky edge case by using some higher-level concepts in C++, without runtime speed penalty.  In particular, range-based `for` and the use of `std::string` as a standard container means we can implement this with no bounds tests or pointer arithmetic to get wrong:

```
#include <string>

std::string hexlify(const std::string& s)
{
    static auto const to_hex = [](char c)
        {
            c &= 0xf; return c>9 ? c+'a'-10 : c+'0';
        };

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(2 * s.size());

    for (auto b: s) {
        result.push_back(to_hex(b>>4));
        result.push_back(to_hex(b));
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    static auto const test = [](const std::string& in,
                                const std::string& expected)
        {
            return hexlify(in) != expected;
        };

    // We use numeric character escapes to avoid dependence on any
    // specific character coding.
    return test("\60", "30")
        +  test({"\0\0", 1}, "00")
        +  test({"\0\0", 2}, "0000")
        +  test("\377", "ff");
}
```

That's Valgrind-clean.